# ImportError: No module named sentry_sdk.integrations.wsgi

Tags: django, python-3.8, sentry

I'm trying to upgrade the implementation of the old Sentry config to the new one for my wsgi configuration in my django project but I'm getting the following error.

```
ImportError: No module named sentry_sdk.integrations.wsgi
```

Earlier I had:

```
from raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.middleware.wsgi import Sentry
```

Now I have:

```
from sentry_sdk.integrations.wsgi import SentryWsgiMiddleware
```

My sentry init is in settings.py file as:

```
sentry_sdk.init(
dsn=SENTRY_CONFIG.get("dsn", ""),
environment=SENTRY_CONFIG["environment"],
integrations=[
    DjangoIntegration(),
    CeleryIntegration(),
    sentry_logging,
],
attach_stacktrace=True,
send_default_pii=True,
```

)

Using:
Django==4.0.3
sentry-sdk==1.5.8
python3.8

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.integrations.django import DjangoIntegration

sentry_environment = env('SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT',default='local')

sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn=env('SENTRY_DSN'),
    integrations=[DjangoIntegration()],
    traces_sample_rate=1.0,

    # If you wish to associate users to errors (assuming you are using
    # django.contrib.auth) you may enable sending PII data.
    send_default_pii=True,
    environment=sentry_environment,
)
```